# Estoy intentando resolver este problema, cuando hago correr el programa, este no me funciona correctamente ¿Alguien tiene la respuesta?

Tags: python

```py
def main ():
    impares == ""
    pares = ""
    for num in range(1,87):
        if num%2 == 0: # es un numero par
            pares+=str(num) +" "
            else:
            impares+=str(num)+ " "
            print("este es el resultado:")
            print(pares)
            print(impares)
            if _name_ == '_main_':
              main()
```

Comment: Bienvenido/a a [es.so]: haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio, y lee [ask] para formular mejor tu pregunta. "No me funciona correctamente": ¿qué error tiene? Ponlo en el título. Además, dale formato al código colocando triples acentos graves (```) una línea antes y una después del mismo.

Comment: tengo que adivinar el error o nos dirás por que no funciona?

Comment: Bueno... Para empezar haces una comparación en lugar de una asignación con impares... Luego la indentacion no es correcta if/else... Pero me parece que podrías al menos decirnos que error te da, para orientar mejor la solución o la explicación...

Comment: aparte del indentado (he mandado edición para corregirlo) y de la igualdad de impares que comenta @Jakala, también ocurre que `if _name_ == '_main_':` no es correcto, deberías comprobar la variable __name__. El valor correcto para saber si estás ejecutando este script y no importándolo sería: '__main__' por lo que el if sería `if __name__ == '__main__':`

Answer (score 0):

en lo que enviaste tiene algunos problemas de identacion y la primera asignacion de la variable "impares" seria solo un "=" y el if para correr el programa main debe estar al mismo nivel de identacion que la funcion que invocas.

```
def main ():
 impares = ""
 pares = ""
 for num in range(1,87):
   if num%2 == 0: # es un numero par
     pares+=str(num) +" "
   else:
     impares+=str(num)+ " "
     print("este es el resultado:")
     print(pares)
     print(impares)
if __name__ == "__main__":
 main()
```